# Allow non-root process to access all home directories without compromising security?

Tags: permissions, security, users

Any ideas how to allow one non-root process to access (read&write) all home directories without compromising security? Normal users should not have access to each other's home directories.

All ideas are welcome, even crazy ones (nfs&kerberos setups?) :)

I basically need to create web interface for user home directories, where the non-root process is the web server process.

New files should have the home directory user as the owner. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

We're going to need more info if you are looking for a complete answer. From what I understood, you may want to look into [Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). It is supported by many Unices and will give you better control over what user gets access to which file.

Use with care and try it in a VM first if you're not 100% comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the difficulty is that home directories are not publicly executable in your environment.

You can put an [access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) on all home directories that gives a particular user or group execution permission to the directory. The web server will then potentially be able to access any file in users' home directories, which may provide ways to escalate privileges (at least, this will broaden the impact of a local file access vulnerability). For example, under Solaris or Linux, make sure the home filesystem is mounted with the `acl` option, and run

```
setfacl -m user:www-data:x /home/*
```

(integrate that into your account creation setup). Then tell your users that their `~/public_html` directory must be readable by the `www-data` user; they can run this command:

```
setfacl -R -m default:user:www-data:rx ~/public_html
setfacl -R -m user:www-data:rx ~/public_html
```

Another possibility is to mount all the users' `public_html` directories in a separate place on the filesystem. This approach has the advantage that the permissions on the home directories won't matter; it even allows the web server to run chroooted. Under Linux, you can do this for a home directory:

```
mount --bind /home/joe/public_html /srv/homepages/joe
```

The `public_html` directory and its contents still need to be made accessible to `www-data`.

A variant on the Linux bind mount method uses the [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs) filesystem. This method works on any OS that supports bindfs (which is most unices) and does not require any ACL settings, at the cost that any file under `public_html` will be made available for reading by the web server.

```
bindfs -u www-data -p 500 /home/joe/public_html /srv/homepages/joe
```